# Team City + Git SSH agent-side checkout. : Need SSH_KEY error

Tags: git, ssh, teamcity, unfuddle

I set up git VCS using SSH authentication.

1. Default private key
2. Keys are both on server and on agent (different machines, both run Mac OS)
3. I am doing Agent-side checkout
4. "Test connection" returns successful result
5. Locally on agent machine I can easily clone repository. So keys a registered and work well.
6. I am using Unfuddle as repository server

I am getting the following error when run the configuration:

> Failed to collect changes, error: Error collecting changes for VCS
>   repository '"*******" {instance id=67, parent internal id=10, parent
>   id=******Mac*******, description:
>   "git@*******.unfuddle.com:******/********.git#refs/heads/master"}'
>   'git fetch' command failed. stderr:
>   git@*******.unfuddle.com:******/********git: Need SSH_KEY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was on Unfuddle side. Now the fixed it and it works great. 
Here is the thread at JetBrains support: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-38512